# Custom arguments in an environment xparse

Tags: environments, expl3, xparse, arguments, l3keys

Is it possible to create an environment with required arguments that would represent some changes in the environment using only `xparse` package without `environ`?

To be more specific I'd like to make an environment for an integral substitution that would receive a required argument: `line`, `brace` or `wave`. Or at least `l`, `b`, `w` if it's not possible with words.

```
\begin{subs}{MY ARGUMENT}
...
\end{subs}
```

Here are the examples how it should work:

1․ uses `|` at both sides

```
\begin{equation}
\int =
\begin{subs}{l}
...
\end{subs}
\end{equation}
```

[image: line]

2․ uses `[` and `]`

```
\begin{equation}
\int =
\begin{subs}{b}
...
\end{subs}
\end{equation}
```

[image: brace]

3․ uses `\lwavy` and `\rwavy`

```
\begin{equation}
\int =
\begin{subs}{w}
...
\end{subs}
\end{equation}
```

[image: wave]

Also it would be really nice if it used wavy lines when you don't specify anything

```
\begin{subs}
...
\end{subs}
```

---

Just for reference that's how it's hardcoded right now:

```
\;\left \lwavy \:\begin{aligned}
{
...
}
\end{aligned}\;\right \rwavy \;
```

*P.S never mind that random stuff on screenshots, it's just for the demonstration.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without absorbing the contents.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347545/4427
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE10
  <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mnlargesymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lwavy}{\mathopen}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rwavy}{\mathclose}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{subs}{O{wave}}
 {
  \left
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {line}{|}
    {brack}{[}
    {wave}{\lwavy}
   }
  \begin{aligned}
 }
 {
  \end{aligned}
  \right
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {line}{|}
    {brack}{]}
    {wave}{\rwavy}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\int=\begin{subs}
& y=5+x && dt=dx \\
& dy=dx && \text{I love unicorns} \\
& \text{My text here} && z=\sqrt{y-5x^2}
\end{subs}
\]

\[
\int=\begin{subs}[line]
& y=5+x && dt=dx \\
& dy=dx && \text{I love unicorns} \\
& \text{My text here} && z=\sqrt{y-5x^2}
\end{subs}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I wanted. 
The only thing -- I replaced `O` with `G` to have this argument in curly brackets.

Comment: @antshar Don’t. Optional arguments go in brackets. You gain nothing by twisting the syntax.